# failed to open stream: Permission denied in magento duplicate image removing code

Tags: magento-1.9

```
include('app/Mage.php');
//Mage::App('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ob_implicit_flush (1);

$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$i =0;
$total = count($_products);
$count = 0;
foreach($_products as $_prod)
{
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prod->getId());
    $_md5_values = array();

    //protected base image
    $base_image = $_product->getImage();
    if($base_image != 'no_selection')
    {
        $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $base_image  ;

        if(file_exists($filepath))
            $_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
    }

    $i ++;
    echo "rn processing product $i of $total ";

    // Loop through product images
    $_images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if($_images){
        foreach($_images as $_image){
            //protected base image
            if($_image->getFile() == $base_image)
                continue;

            $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $_image->getFile()  ;
            if(file_exists($filepath))
                $md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
            else
                continue;

            if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
            {
                $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),  $_image->getFile());
                echo "rn removed duplicate image from ".$_product->getSku();
                $count++;
            } else {
                $_md5_values[] = $md5;
            }

        }
    }

}
echo "rnrn finished removed $count duplicated images";
```

Comment: Where from you access file? i mean on which location you have placed file?

Comment: file placed in initial root folder of project folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this code But i have not tested

```
<?php
include('app/Mage.php');
//Mage::App('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ob_implicit_flush (1);

$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$i =0;
$total = count($_products);
$count = 0;
foreach($_products as $_prod)
{
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prod->getId());
    $_md5_values = array();

    //protected base image
    $base_image = $_product->getImage();
    if($base_image != 'no_selection') {
        $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $base_image  ;

        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            chmod($filepath, 0777);
            $_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath)); 
            chmod($filepath, 0655);
        }
    }

    $i ++;
    echo "rn processing product $i of $total ";

    // Loop through product images
    $_images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if($_images){
        foreach($_images as $_image){
            //protected base image
            if($_image->getFile() == $base_image)
                continue;

            $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $_image->getFile()  ;
            if(file_exists($filepath)) {
                chmod($filepath, 0777);
                $md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
                chmod($filepath, 0655);
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }


            if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
            {
                $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),  $_image->getFile());
                echo "rn removed duplicate image from ".$_product->getSku();
                $count++;
            } else {
                $_md5_values[] = $md5;
            }

        }
    }

}
echo "rnrn finished removed $count duplicated images";
```

Comment: i got same error with your code, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\giri\media/catalog/product): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\giri\dup.php on line 27' in C:\wamp\www\giri\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245

Answer (score 0):

remove .htaccess from media folder while you performing this script.

It is working for me

```
<?php
include('app/Mage.php');
//Mage::App('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ob_implicit_flush (1);

$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$i =0;
$total = count($_products);
$count = 0;
foreach($_products as $_prod)
{
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prod->getId());
    $_md5_values = array();

    //protected base image
    $base_image = $_product->getImage();
    if($base_image != 'no_selection') {
        $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $base_image  ;

        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            chmod($filepath, 0777);
            $_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath)); 
            chmod($filepath, 0655);
        }
    }

    $i ++;
    echo "rn processing product $i of $total ";

    // Loop through product images
    $_images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if($_images){
        foreach($_images as $_image){
            //protected base image
            if($_image->getFile() == $base_image)
                continue;

            $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $_image->getFile()  ;
            if(file_exists($filepath)) {
                chmod($filepath, 0777);
                $md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
                chmod($filepath, 0655);
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }


            if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
            {
                $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),  $_image->getFile());
                echo "rn removed duplicate image from ".$_product->getSku();
                $count++;
            } else {
                $_md5_values[] = $md5;
            }

        }
    }

}
echo "rnrn finished removed $count duplicated images";
```

Comment: there is no htaccess file in media folder, which is only in initial root folder